# HDMI not Working on Ubuntu 18.04 with Dual Graphics

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, hdmi

I got an Alienware e13 r3 laptop on which I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows in dual boot.

If I use Windows the HDMI works like a charme, but in Ubuntu it just does not do anything when I plug-in the cable.

I got 2 graphic cards in the laptop. The output of

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
```

is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

Maybe the problem has something to do with this?

Output of `xrandr` is

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 160mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  59.95  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     59.96    60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I really do not have any clue what to do and I really need that monitor working.... 
I checked some other threads about the HDMI problems in 18.04 but nothing worked out for me or the threads were just never answered by anyone. I hope this one will be different :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have exactly the same issue

Comment: no, sorry. i still got no clue...

Comment: I managed to fix this. I need to turn off Secure Boot in my UEFI settings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by disabling Secure Boot in my UEFI settings. Then I opened NVIDIA X Server, changed the prime profile to Intel (Power Saving), restarted my laptop and then switched it back to NVIDIA (performance)